# How to get value of a variable in SonarQube (custom-rules )?

Tags: java, sonarqube, rules

I started working on sonar custom-rule recently so I am new to it. While programming I was not able to access the value of a variable.

.g. Consider this simple example

```
// Input program file

public void myMethod()
    {
        String a = "Name";
        String b ="Address"
        myMethod2(b);
    }
```

How do I get the value and name of variable `a` and `b` for above example.

I have tried using `LiteralTree` but I am only able to get the value and using `Identifier Tree` I am only able to get the name of the identifier.

How do I get the name and the value of a variable/identifier?

Answer (score 3):

You should use `VariableTree`, and via it's `simpleName()` method you can access `IdentifierTree` and `initializer()` allows working with initializer (it might not be present, in which case it will be `null`). However, this works only for variable declaration. For assignments, you will need to use `AssignmentExpressionTree`, because that's another grammar element.

Depending on what you want to achieve, you might need to use semantic model (by using `IdentifierTree.symbol()`, which can, for example, provide you all the usages of the variable by `Symbol.usages()` method.

Comment: Thanks! It worked for Variable declaration. But how do I get it for assignment?

**Consider this simple example**
`Class A
{
 public void methodA(String name)
 {
  //some code
 }
}

Class B
{
 String name;
 public void methodB()
 {
  name = "XYZ";
  A a = new A();
  a.methodA(name);
 }
}`

If I use visitMethodInvocation method, through that I will get the argument (name) but how will I get it’s value since it is stored in AssignmentExpressionTree as you mentioned above.

Comment: You won't be able to track values of variables with only syntactic approach, because things will get complex very quickly with more advanced control flow structures. A technique to be able to do such things is called Symbolic Execution. While SonarJava has Symbolic Execution engine, this is not exposed via public API yet and it's not something we have in plan for the time being.